# Symfony2 @Assert\IsTrue not translated

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity that contains a specific validation, the validation work, but the error message is not translated. 
This is the entity code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Parameters
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Parameters
{
   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="paramValue", type="string", length=255)
     * @return bool
     */
    private $paramValue;

/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue(message="bobundle_config_langue")
 */
public function islangcorrect()
{
// validation 
}
```

I work on symfony 2.7,Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is `bobundle_config_langue` a valid key for the translator? We can't help much without seeing your configuration. We don't read tea leaves here.

Comment: Plus `bobundle_config_langue` must be in the correct domain

Comment: Hi, yes I 'm sure that "bobundle_config_langue" is the correct key and placed in the correct domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translations used by validator must be stored in a different file than regular translations.

For yml format and en locale you would have:

- regular translation file:
  YourBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml
- validator translation file: YourBundle/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml

[Symfony 2.7 - translations](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/translation.html)

[Symfony 2.7 - Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/validation.html)